# Proper use of artifacts.require?

Tags: truffle

I am trying to understand how `artifacts.require` should be used.  I've seen the standard paragraph describing it as being for migrations and testing.  From this I infer that the globally scoped `artifacts` with its method `require` are automatically defined by the truffle executable tool when doing migrations or running tests.  However, I am working with some code that uses `artifacts.require` outside the context of any migrations or tests, rather, this code just needs to do the usual `at` and `new`.  However,  in this context, the object `artifacts` is not defined.

Do I have the right picture here?  Is this an appropriate use of `artifacts.require`?  If so, what must be done to make it be defined outside of migrations and testing?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

artifacts.require really isn't meant to be used outside of a test.  this is where it is defined: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-core/blob/3e96337c32aaae6885105661fd1a6792ab4494bf/lib/test.js#L240

when in production code you should load the compiled contract into your application using truffle-contract https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract

here is a short example (from http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/packages-npm#within-javascript-code and see 
http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/contracts#making-a-transaction )

```javascript
var contract = require("truffle-contract");
var contractJson = require("example-truffle-library/build/contracts/SimpleNameRegistry.json");
var SimpleNameRegistry = contract(contractJson);
SimpleNameRegistry
  .deployed()
  .then(function(instance) {
     return instance.setRegistry(address);
   })
  .then(function(result) {
    // If this callback is called, the transaction was successfully processed.
    alert("Transaction successful!")
  })
  .catch(function(e) {
    // There was an error! Handle it.
  });
```

Comment: How do you get the compiled code from a package installed through EthPM? The example in the truffle docs uses artifacts.require outside of a test, which doesn't seem to work in production: http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/packages-ethpm